# Evento click en tabla HTML input hidden

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código donde obtengo los datos de una fila mediante un evento de un botón.

```js
$('#tbl').on('click', 'button.replay', function(e) {

    var cliente = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var cantidad = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=id]').val();
    
    console.log('Cliente ' +cliente+' id '+id);
        
  });
```

```html
     

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Comentario</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody_folio">
                <tr>
                <td>CL 1</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-warning replay' type='button' name='button'>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>agregar a pedido</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>CL 2</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>Pedido urgente</td>
                <td>
                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-warning replay' type='button' name='button'>
                 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
                <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-right'></i> agregar a pedido</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
```

Me gustaría hacer lo mismo pero al hacer click del mouse en la tabla `$('#tbl').click( function(event)` . He buscado ejemplos pero no he podido rescatar el `input hidden`. Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Hola, amigo, yo no entendí muy bien el problema que tienes. ¿Qué de qué quieres rescatar al darle click al elemento "#tbl"? Además veo que este id se lo asignas a la tabla, entonces solo va a funcionar cuando le hagas click a la tabla, ¿este comportamiennto está bien? Espero me expliques para ayudarte

Comment: @FernandoTorres sii, haciendo click sobre la tabla

Comment: Para traer el input hidden que tiene el nombre id puedes usar directamente esto: `$('input[name=id]').val()`

Comment: @JuniorUsca para usarlo despues en un ajax y obtener la info cliente.

Comment: Es que lo que quieres no tiene sentido con lo que tienes en la tabla, yo creo que está mal planteado todo, porque sabes algo? Si tienes muchos input hidden y quieres disparar un evento al darle click a la tabla, cuándo sabrías qué input hidden tomar de tantos que tienes? Más bien yo creo que te refieres a que mejor el evento onclick se dispare al darle click en cualquier fila de tu tabla, no? Así al darle click a cualquier fila de tu tabla ya sabrías qué input tomar

Comment: @FernandoTorres y al agregar `$(this).closest('tr')`  no me encontraría el mas cercano?

Comment: No sabría decirte porque no sé qué necesitas. Pienso que tu pregunta es muy abierta entonces y está basada en opiniones, creo que debes enfocar bien tu pregunta y poner bien todo lo que tienes y lo que esperas que haga tu código poniendo algunos ejemplos, actualízala en orden de que seas muy claro con lo que necesitas

Comment: Y no sería más sencillo, controlar el evento al hacer click en una fila? 
$('#tbl tr').click(Aquí la función);  Y el this de esto, sería el TR, sólo tendrías que buscar el name o id del elemento que deseas recoger.Más tarde te escribo si no te ha sido suficiente y te paso un ejemplo

Comment: @FernandoTorres la idea mia es poder hacer lo mismo que hago al presionar el boton, pero quiero hacer al momento de hacer `CLICK` con el mouse sobre el `td` recuperar los datos de esa fila y dentro de esos datos hay un `input hidden` que es la Id del cliente para poder mostrar los datos relacionado a ese cliente

Answer (score -3):

Aqui encontre la solucion.

```js
   $('#tbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){

    var cliente = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var cantidad = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=id]').val();
    
    console.log('Cliente ' +cliente+' id '+id);
        
  });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Comentario</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody_folio">
                <tr>
                <td>CL 1</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>CL 2</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>Pedido urgente</td>
                <td>
               
                 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="33">
             
                </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td>CL 1</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="11">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td>CL 4</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="21">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td>CL 5</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td>CL 6</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="71">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td>CL 7</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td>CL 8</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="15">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
<tr>
                <td>CL 9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Pedido 1</td>
                <td>
              
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="99">
                
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
```